# How to sort the Ionic grid using drag and drop?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop

is ionic contains this feature or using in angular ? below is the jquery link

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

same thing am looking for.

Comment: what solution did you use?

Answer (score 0):

No Ionic does not provide the requirement that you are looking for, but ionic provides Reorder feature in list view.

Use this link for further reference
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/